# How to create a repeating non-capturing group?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create what I think is a repeating non-capturing group, and I just can't figure out how.

In plain words, I want to match:

Any number which is both

- Preceded by any amount of blocks that doesn't contain a space, but is not either just a number.
- Followed by any amount of blocks that doesn't contain a space, but is not either just a number.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/100hA4/2) is what I tried:

Pattern: (?:\w.)+(\d+)(?:.\w+)+

Test Set:

```
3.AAA
AAA.BBB
AAA.3.BBB
AAA.3.B555B
AAA.3.BBB.4
AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC
AAA.3.BBB.CCC
AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4
AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD
```

I would want it to match only to:

```
AAA.3.BBB
AAA.3.B555B
AAA.3.BBB.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC
```

Note: I saw some other posts asking the same-ish question, but I can't use the answers because they were all like "Instead of trying to repeat a group, just match 'this' and it will work for your specific case".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Q9LCNR/1)

```
^(?:(?!(?:\.|^)\d+\.)\S)+\.\d+\.(?:(?!\.\d+(?:\.|$))\S)+$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
3.AAA
AAA.BBB
AAA.3.BBB
AAA.3.B555B
AAA.3.BBB.4
AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC
AAA.3.BBB.CCC
AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4
AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD
```

### Output

```
AAA.3.BBB
AAA.3.B555B
AAA.3.BBB.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:(?!(?:\.|^)\d+\.)\S)+` Match the following one or more times

  - `(?!(?:\.|^)\d+\.)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

    - `(?:\.|^)` Match either of the following

      - `\.` Match a literal dot character `.`
      - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
    - `\d+` Match one or more digits
    - `\.` Match a literal dot character `.`
  - `\S` Match any non-whitespace character
- `\.` Match a literal dot character `.`
- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `\.` Match a literal dot chracter `.`
- `(?:(?!\.\d+(?:\.|$))\S)+` Match the following one or more times

  - `(?!\.\d+(?:\.|$))` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

    - `\.` Match a literal dot chracter `.`
    - `\d+` Match one or more digits
    - `(?:\.|$)` Match either of the following

      - `\.` Match a literal dot chracter `.`
      - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
  - `\S` Match any non-whitespace character
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Wow. It's perfect, and now, I have to understand it so one day I can explain it to someone! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Tipx you're very welcome! I just added an explanation, but you can also click the regex101 link (at the top of the **Code** section) and hover the token/read the explanation top-right of the regex101 page.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading it on regex101. Was waiting the mandatory remaining 23secs before I could accept your answer! :-P

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit simpler solution:

```
^(?:(?!\d+\.)\w+\.)+\d+(?:\.(?!\d+(?=\.|$))\w+)+$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5Cd%2B%5C.%29%5Cw%2B%5C.%29%2B%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%28%3F!%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29%29%5Cw%2B%29%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=3.AAA%0D%0AAAA.BBB%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB%0D%0AAAA.3.B555B%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB.4%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB.4.CCC%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB.CCC%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB.CCC.4%0D%0AAAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4%0D%0AZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD&o=m) (since it is a multiline demo, `\r?` has to be added before `$`, it is not necessary when matching standalone strings).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?!\d+\.)\w+\.)+` - 1 or more occurrences (due to `(?:...)+`) of any 1+ word chars (letters, digits, `_` - due to `\w+`) that are not all digits followed with a dot (**note** that to match only letters and digits, you need to use `[\w-[_]]` or `[^\W_]` instead of `\w`, *or* if you are really after matching the blocks that may even have symbols or punctuation, replace `\w` with `[^\s.]` - any char but whitespace or dot)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.(?!\d+(?=\.|$))\w+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?!\d+(?=\.|$))` - not followed with 1+ digits (`\d+`) followed with a dot or end of string
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/OsVG5t):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lst = new List<string> {"3.AAA", "AAA.BBB", "AAA.3.BBB", "AAA.3.B555B", "AAA.3.BBB.4", 
            "AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC", "AAA.3.BBB.CCC", "AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4", "AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD",
            "ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB","ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4","ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.4.CCC", "ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC",
            "ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4", "ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC.4.DDD"};
        var rx = new Regex(@"^(?:(?!\d+\.)[^\s.]+\.)+\d+(?:\.(?!\d+(?=\.|$))[^\s.]+)+$", 
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
        foreach (var s in lst) 
        {
            if (rx.IsMatch(s))
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }       
}
```

Results:

```
AAA.3.BBB
AAA.3.B555B
AAA.3.BBB.CCC
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB
ZZZ.AAA.3.BBB.CCC
```